# change color of top 10 list items in jquery drag and drop list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a list of 20 items. I am using jquery drag and drop to allow the user to sort the list of items. I would like the top 10 items in the list to remain the same color, lets say yellow, as the items are rearranged. For instance, if the #19 item is dragged up to within the top ten, the #10 item will be pushed to #11 and the items which should be yellow would be #'s 1,2,3,4,5,19,6,7,8,9.

No matter which order, the top ten should remain yellow. The rest are just black

I can not figure out how to do this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not tell us your html so I have to guess your using a html list. When sorting stops you have to get the position of the element and descide which color to assign

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop

and use [`index`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index) method

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/txm9y/

```
$( "#sortable" )
    .sortable({
        stop: function(event, ui){
            $(this).trigger("markTopTen");
        }
    })
    .disableSelection()
    .bind("markTopTen", function() {
        $(this).find("li")
            .removeClass("topTen")
            .each(function(index){
            if(index < 10)
                $(this).addClass("topTen");
        });
    })
    .trigger("markTopTen");
```

Start sorting. Top ten will remain yellow while others are black.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a callback function when drop the element and set the bacgground to be yellow for the first ten items. See this link below for the drop event details
http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop
The callback event looks something like

```
// pseudo code
function() {
  all_items.each(e, i) {
    if(i<10) set_bg(yelow, e);
    else set_bg(black, e);
  }
}
```

see this, I tried in fiddle, it will simply put an alert box, try to do the above logic here

```
<script>
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
    stop: function() {
        // your code goes here   
        alert('stop event')
    }
});
</script>
```